# How to display an image when hover and clicked on the respective div

Tags: jquery, html, css

CSS:

```
.imgECheck {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 5px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    display: none;
}
.imgFCheck {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 5px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    display: none;
}
```

How can I achieve the function in the JQuery above.

Comment: I tried this: `$(this).children("img").fadeIn();` which didn't work for me.

Comment: Can we get a little more information about exactly what you're trying to accomplish - make reference to your markup classnames, what your functions are supposed to do, etc.

Comment: I was able to figure it out with some assistance from below. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

So after more info here's what I think you need:

```
$(".btn-small").on("hover", function(){
    $(".imgECheck").addClass("show");
});


$(".btn-small").click(function(){
    $(".imgECheck").removeClass("show");
    $(".imgFCheck").addClass("show");
});
```

Comment: There are two images and my hover and click is conflicting now :/

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do the same thing in both click and hover. why? can you post a jsfiddle?

Comment: for `mouseover` function, I would like to display the image with the 'imgECheck' and `mouseout` function, I would like to hide the image with the `imgECheck`. When the div is clicked I would like to display the `imgFCheck` for the DIV clicked. If a div has the image which is already displaying the `imgFCheck` class image, the hover function shouldn't fire.

Comment: great! if either of our answers helped, please remember to accept them.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
    $(".btn-small").on("click", function () {
       $('.imgFCheck').hide();
       $(this).find('.imgFCheck').show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try bellow code

```
 $(function () {
    $('.imgFCheck').hide();

  $(document).on('click','.btn-small', function () {

    $(this).find('.imgFCheck').show().toggleClass('is-clicked');

  });

  $(document).on('hover','.btn-small', function () {
     if(!$(this).find('.imgFCheck').hasClass('is-clicked'))
      {
        $(this).find('.imgFCheck').toggle();
       }
   });

});
```